# RecyclerView height issue in API 17 and API 16 - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing `RecyclerView` in my app to show a list of stuff. On my LG Nexus 5 (Android 5.1 M), if i set target sdk to 16 or 17 (basically to simulate what's happening on those phones with api 16, 17) my row height of the list changes dramatically.

However, this doesn't occur on API 18 or 18+. I cannot really figure out why this happens and what is the optimal approach to tackle this issue.

**One More Thing:** I use an `ImageView` inside the list row. This is happening when in my `ImageView` i am loading the images from the server. I use `ImageLoader` library to do this. However if I use static images, then i don't have this issue

Comment: so no one has encountered this issue before?

Comment: Can you paste your row xml layout?

Comment: Please paste your style.xml too

Answer (score 4):

"if I use static images, then i don't have this issue"
When using static images, they are loaded in during [`onLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for your `ImageView`. When the image is loaded in during the layout, it affects the measured size in the [`onMeasure()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) pass.

When the image isn't set statically(i.e. pulled down over network async), the `ImageView` can't rely on the size of the image to determine its measured size. When the image is loaded, it will be shrunk to fit within the existing measured `ImageView`.

**Solutions:**

- Specify a [`minHeight`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minHeight) on your `ImageView` or row layout
- OR Specify a fixed height on your `ImageView` or row layout

If you know what size you want for your row, you should use the fixed height.

There are default styles for `RecyclerView` that can set attributes like `minHeight` for your row layout that can vary across API versions. Thus without explicitly setting a fixed or `minHeight` yourself, you can see different behavior across API versions.

Comment: Note: There's a known issue with minHeight on RecyclerView: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772

Answer (score 1):

I also have problem with height of recyclerView so found a solution.
Give height from java code. It works for me.

```html
recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
  new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
 @Override
 public void onGlobalLayout() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
        //use your layout
recyclerTagScroll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) recyclerTagScroll
     .getLayoutParams();

  params.height = recyclerTagScroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
  recyclerTagScroll.setLayoutParams(params);
 }
});
```